# VS2012: Changing intermediate directory to TEMP folder causes linker not updating executable

Tags: visual-studio-2012

This is really weird issue I ran into and took hours to narrow it down.

Steps to reproduce:

1. On Windows 8 create a simple VC++ project (console) in Visual Studio 2012.
2. Build and run executable.
3. If you make changes to source file and build, linker updates the executable. This is expected.
4. Now change intermediate directory (under Project Properties -> General) to $TEMP folder which by default is:

> C:\Users\ *username* \AppData\Local\Temp

5. Now if you make changes to source and build, it shows build successful but executable will **not** be updated

It's indeed weird and surprisingly if we change intermediate folder to anything other than $TEMP, it works perfect.

Any idea why this is happens?

Comment: Negative voter please explain why? This is not yadda yadda question. This is genuine issue. I spent hours to narrow it down. Have you ever tried it yourself before clicking on down arrow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of search and investigation I finally found it in a corner of Microsoft website this was genuine issue in Visual Studio. It has been reported [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/760370/linker-does-not-link-if-intermediate-directory-with-changed-object-files-is-on-another-drive)

And as per stated there:

> Posted by Microsoft on 11/16/2012 at 7:08 PM
>
> Thanks for the log. The build system doesn't support the Intermediate
>   directory as and/or a subfolder of the Temp directory.
>
> IntDir = c:\temp\buildme\
>   TEMP = c:\temp 
>   Could you change your IntDir to another folder and see if the issue still reproduces?
>
> Thanks

And

> Posted by Microsoft on 4/29/2014 at 12:31 PM
>
> Thank you for reporting this issue. This issue has been fixed in Visual Studio 2013. You can install a trial version of Visual Studio 2013 with the fix from: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9832436